# Como conectar express con mongo atlas usando mongoose

Tags: mongodb, vscode, mongoose, sql-server-express, mongoatlas

Estoy haciendo un proyecto escolar y me piden que tenga mi base de datos en la nube, actualmente la tengo en local usando mongodb y no se como realizar la conexión para recibir los datos en mi proyecto de react, mongo atlas me da este ejemplo pero no se como utilizarlo:

```
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.x3tdprh.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0";

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  }
});

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client.connect();
    // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);

//para la conexión local actualmente lo tengo asi:

import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const connectDB= async ()=>{
    try {
        // coneccion con la base de dato
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
        .then(() => console.log('Conectado a la base de datos'))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```